# Two Buttons with different action on same php page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PHP page with two Buttons named as Save and Submit.One for Saving form Data and other for submiting the final data.

```
<button id="save" name="save" onclick="saveForm();">Save</button>

<button id="submit" name="submit" onclick="validate();">Submit</button>
```

here are the two JavaScript functions:

```
function saveForm() {
    document.submission.method = "POST";
    document.submission.action = "SubmissionCheck.php";
    document.submission.submit();
}

function validate() {
    // some validation code here
    // after validation the rest will work
    document.submission.method = "POST";
    document.submission.action = "SubmissionCheck.php";
    document.submission.submit();
}
```

In 'SubmissionCheck.php' page I have defined two separate actions for save and submit button, but I am facing the same process of submit button when I click the save button. How do I solve this? Any one help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: make difference in the actions or set the name for input then get the input name that sends the request and do the appropriate job.

Comment: my actions are different and that works fine.but the same function of submit button calling in save button

Comment: I've added some information, but rereading your question for the third time what exactly is going on? Is your save function in php running, or the `saveForm()` js every time? or am I overlooking what you asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button id="save" value="save" name="method" onclick="saveForm();">Save</button>

<button id="submit" value="submit" name="method" onclick="validate();">Submit</button>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["method"])){
   if($_POST["method"] == "save"){
      echo "Saving File";
     }elseif($_POST["method"] == "submit"){
      echo "Submitting File";
     }
  }
```

When you are doing what you are trying to do I tend to keep my name's the same. So that I can test against them. I generally use names such as `action`, `method`, `mode`,and `data` which I can then test the values. Another good practice I do, is just `var_dump` then entire `$_POST`

**example**

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

By performing these test conditions you can have more control over your code without getting overwhelmed by names. Another thing I like to do is use these for page actions, these `action`,`mode`,`method` help me generate the exact page the user is looking for.

**example**

```
<input type="text" value="" name="method" placeholder="Insert a method">
<input type="text" value="" name="action" placeholder="Insert a action">
<input type="text" value="" name="mode" placeholder="Insert a mode">
```

Then when submitted I can use these like so

```
$path = "";
if(isset($_POST["method"])){
   path.="method=".$_POST["method"];
   if(isset($_POST["action"])){
      path.="&action=".$_POST["action"];
      if(isset($_POST["mode"])){
      path.="&mode=".$_POST["mode"];
     }
   }
  header("Location: /path/".$path);
}
```

This will output three ways... if only method, if method and action, and if method,action,and mode. So generally speaking, testing against universal names sometimes is better. Hope this little walk down PHP `$_POST` usage helps you a little bit.

**note** I never sanitized any of the `$_POST` values, but if you are using them as a path you really should, or if you are access mySQL database use `mysqli_real_escape_string` and other sanitation methods.

Also is your forms default action being prevented, because since you have no values, `$_POST` will be empty every time. Unless it's prevented then submitted correctly.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    //buttons
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can differentiate in actions like this

```
function saveForm() {
document.submission.method = "POST";
document.submission.action = "SubmissionCheck.php";
document.submission.submit();
 }
 function validate() {
--some validation code here---
--after validation the rest will work--
document.submission.method = "POST";
document.submission.action = "SubmissionCheck.php?validate";
document.submission.submit();
}
```

then in SubmissionCheck.php file check

```
if(isset($_GET['validate']))
{
  // perform actions for validation
}
```

Comment: to perform client side validation the best option is to use jquery validation plugin , and it will also perform form submission after validation via ajax you can find here [link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Not everything needs a plugin. jQuery is already goobered up as it is, why add nonessential plugins, when validation can be performed with Vanilla. Just my personally feelings.

Answer (score -1):

check isset:

```
if (isset($_POST["save"])) 
{
    echo "save action";    
}
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{  
    echo "submit action";
}
```